Why does a refinement of a tagged partitions make it's Riemann sum more accurate?
I have seen and understood the proof that how refinement increases the accuracy of the Riemann sum when we consider the lower sum $L(P,f)$ and upper sum $U(P,f)$. But I recently saw another definition of a Riemann integral which involves tagged partition.
Informally speaking , I think that the upper and lower sums also involve tagged partitions , just in particular that their tags are maximum and minimum values for the sub-intervals.
My doubt is regarding the refinement of a tagged partition. I could easily see geometrically that how ; for lower and upper sums,  refinement of an interval makes the area associated with it closer to the actual area. But , if the tags could be any general point in those sub-intervals , how can we prove it ?

@HansLundmark corrected. Thanks

@HansLundmark I missed that it's a noun.

Refinement of a partition does not guarantee that Riemann sums are closer to the integral value for every choice of partition tags.
Consider a a partition $P = \{x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n:a=x_0 <x_1< \ldots< x_n = b\}$ and a non-constant, continuous function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$.  By the mean value theorem there exists $c_j \in (x_{j-1},x_j)$ for each index $j$ such that
$$ \int_{x_{j-1}}^{x_j} f(x) \, dx= f(c_j)(x_j-x_{j-1})$$
Choosing the tags $T = \{c_1,\ldots,c_n\}$ it follows that the Riemman sum corresponding to partition $P$ with tags $T$ is given by
$$S(f,P,T) = \sum_{j=1}^n f(c_j)(x_j- x_{j-1})= \sum_{j=1}^n \int_{x_{j-1}}^{x_j} f(x) \, dx= \int_a^b f(x) \, dx,$$
and the error of approximation by the sum is $\displaystyle E_{P,T} =\left|S(f,P,T)- \int_a^b f(x) \, dx\right| = 0$.
For any refined partition $P' \supset P$, we can always choose tags $T'$ such that the error $E_{P',T'}>0$ when $f$ is a non-constant function.
For a specific example, take $f(x) = x$, partition $P=\{0,1\}$, and tags $T = \{\frac{1}{2}\}$ where $E_{P,T}=0$ since
$$S(f,P,T) = \frac{1}{2}(1-0) = \frac{1}{2} = \int_0^1 x \, dx $$
For the refined partition $P'= \{0,\frac{1}{2},1\}$ and tags $T'= \{\frac{1}{2},1\}$ we have
$$S(f,P',T') = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}-0)+1 (1- \frac{1}{2})= \frac{3}{4},$$
and $E_{P',T'}= |\frac{3}{4}- \frac{1}{2}|= \frac{1}{4} > E_{P,T} = 0$.

Thanks. But isn't this conclusion incompatible with how a reimann integral is defined.

No.  Eventually as the partition norm (length of largest subinterval) tends to zero the Riemann sum for any choice of tags tends to the value of the integral.  In that sense, making partitions finer improves accuracy. However I gave you a simple counterexample to your statement that a sum with any choice of tags for a refined partition is more accurate than every sum for the unrefined partition.

My example even uses a continuous function which must be Riemann integrable.

Convergence of upper and lower sums to the integral $I$ is, however,  monotone with respect to partition refinement. If $P’$ is a refinement of $P$, then $0 \leq U(f,P’)-I \leq U(f,P) -  I$

Okay thanks. If I understand it correctly , then you were saying that it gets more accurate with refinement only if number of subintervals tends to be infinitely large (or norm tends to zero) .

@An_Elephant: I don't think saying "more accurate ... only if number of subintervals tends to be infinitely large" is precise, but roughly speaking it is correct.  Since both the integral $I = \int_a^b f$ and any Riemann sum $S(f,P,T)$ are squeezed in between the upper and lower sums corresponding to the partition $P$ we have $|S(f,P,T)- I| \leq U(f,P) - L(f,P)$.  Riemann integrability means that for any $\epsilon >0$ there is a partition $P_\epsilon$ such that if $P$ is a refinement then $|S(f,P,T)- I| \leq U(f,P) - L(f,P)< \epsilon$.

What we can't guarantee is that $|S(f,P',T')- I| \leq |S(f,P,T) - I|$ for every choice of tags $T'$ just because $P'$ is a refinement of $P$.
